# AWS EC2のrootボリュームのディスクパーティションについて

Tags: amazon-ec2

AWS EC2のrootボリュームは、単一のパーティションです。
下記のように構成したいと考えています。

1. EBSは、`/`と`/home`の2つ
2. `/`は、1つのEBSをLVMで`/`と`/var`を２つに分ける

1の理由は、バックアップです。
EBSのスナップショットでバックアップを作成する際にOS部分の`/`とユーザデータの`/home`を分けて取得したいのでEBSは２つと考えました。

2は、`/var`や`/home`が原因でdisk fullになった場合を想定しました。
dockerなどで大きなイメージをpullしてdisk fullになったときに`docker rmi`もできなくなり、EBSを増やして再起動する必要があったからです。また、バックアップのときに`/`と`/var`を一緒に取得できるようにしたいのでEBSで分けることを避けました。

AWS EC2のrootボリュームのディスクパーティションについて、良い事例やアイデアはありますでしょうか。

Comment: https://qiita.com/ymstmsys/items/b292ef1e75dbb64c34d6 を見つけました。元の AMI が HVM タイプであれば、できそうです。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございました。EBSのサイズ変更がオンラインでできるようになったようです。両方試してみようと思います。

Answer (score 0):

`/`と`/home`では求められるバックアップ頻度が異なるため、EBSを分けざるを得ないと思います。今だとEFSも選択肢にあがるかもしれません。

`/var`のdisk fullについてはEBSやパーティションを分ける以外の選択肢として、disk duotaがあるかもしれません。xfsであればディレクトリ単位でdisk quotaを設定できるので、`/var`配下を10GB以下に抑える、といった設定も可能です。